# How to Fetch a large volume data by query for a specific records

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a DB table `Employee` in SQL Server that contains 10,00,000 records. I want this data into multiple files/Query (suppose 10 times) by SQL Query.

So now I want this data in the below way by SQL Query.

```
1st Query - First 1,00,000 Records
2nd Query - Second 1,00,000 Records
3rd Query - Third  1,00,000 Records
.
.
.
.
.
10th Query - Last 1,00,000 Records
```

Please let me know how we can achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to implement something like **pagination**. you can use something like this:

```
;WITH Employee_Result AS
(
    SELECT
        Col1, Col2, ...,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SortCol1, SortCol2, ...) AS RowNum
    FROM Employee
)
SELECT *
FROM Employee_Result
WHERE RowNum >= @Offset
AND RowNum < @Offset + @Limit
```

and `@Offset`, `@Limit` would be 100,000 and ... according to the step you are in.

You also haven't mentioned in which order you want to slice the records, but you can specify that in the `order by` clause.

**Update:** If you are using **SQL Server 2012**, you can use this simpler syntax:

```
SELECT * FROM Employee 
ORDER BY SortCol
OFFSET 100000 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 100000 ROWS ONLY;
```

If you are using **SQL Server 2008**, you can use this as the short form:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Id) AS RowNum
    FROM Employee
) AS DerivedTable
WHERE DerivedTable.RowNum BETWEEN @StartRow AND @EndRow
```

and you should replace variables `@StartRow` and `@EndRow` with your own values.

Comment: Thanks for answering my Query .I tried this query but it is not working. it showing OFFSET as invalid keyword. Currently I am using SQL SERVER. Please suggest what to do.  Thank you

Comment: @SaurabhGupta: I update my answer and added a syntax compatible with **SQL Server 2008**

Comment: @SaurabhGupta: Did you try what I mentioned in update?

Comment: opsss... forgot to inform you.. yes buddy It's awesome and working...thanks a lot for your answer !